# Acceptable load time

Tags: android-layout

I am working  on a point of sale (POS vending machine) project which has many images on the screen where the customer is expected to browse almost all of them. 
here are my questions.
1. Can you please suggest me test cases for testing load time for images
2. what is the acceptable load time for these images on screen. 
3. Do we have any standers for testing these kind of acceptable load time.

Thanks,
TR

Answer (score 0):

Well, acceptable load time is as fast as possible! I would try getting them to all load at once and then cache them. That way only the initial load is slow, and once everything is loaded there is no wait.
toggle this css to cache it:

```
img{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I am not developing this application but i am testing.